# Getting a "Type Error" in vb.net code converted from C#

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this code in VB.Net 2010 and I am getting a "type Error" on New().

This code was converted from C#.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Function CredentialGet(ByVal sKey As String, ByRef sCred As String)
    Dim sCredential As Element.Credential

    sCredential  = apiclient.SearchCredentials(sSoftwareKey, SessionID,
        New() {New Element.SearchTerm() With {.FilterKey = "APK", .Value = sKey}})
    sCred = sCredential.CredentialID
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

New() what? You are missing an object name there. You're now passing in an anonymous object.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parentheses for the anonymous type. VB.Net does not use them in that context, but looks for the `With` keyword instead. And functions should return a value. You don't return anything, so use a Sub:

```
Public Sub CredentialGet(ByVal Key As String, ByRef Cred As String)
    Dim Credential As Element.Credential 
    Credential = apiclient.SearchCredentials(sSoftwareKey, SessionID, _
        New With {New Element.SearchTerm() With {.FilterKey = "APK", .Value = Key}})
    Cred = Credential.CredentialID
End Sub
```

I also question this design. It would be better to return a string:

```
Public Function CredentialGet(ByVal Key As String) As String
    Return apiclient.SearchCredentials(sSoftwareKey, SessionID, _
        New With {New Element.SearchTerm() With {.FilterKey = "APK", .Value = Key}}).CredentialID
End Function
```